# Likert scale frequencies and descriptive statistics

Tags: spss

I have 16 statements/variables on Likert scale with 5 categories each statement (1 = Strongly disagree, 2 = Disagree, 3 = Undecided, 4 = Agree, 5 = Strongly Agree). I want to calculate the Mean, Standard deviation and counts for each category for all variables in the same table in SPSS. Can anyone expert with SPSS help?

Comment: Analyse --> Descriptive Statistics --> Descriptives / Frequencies. Once you find your analysis, instead of running it, select `paste`. This will paste the command syntax in a syntax window where you can run it and\or edit it. This will get you started with SPSS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Common commands to generate output in SPSS include `MEANS`, `FREQUENCIES`, `DESCRIPTIVES`, and `CROSSTABS`.  If you want to see information on all variables in the same table `MEANS` and/or `DESCRIPTIVES` will probably be your best.

If your variables are named var1 TO var 16 and there are no missing values that need to be accounted for you can use the following:

```
MEANS var1 TO var16 /CELLS MEAN STDDEV COUNT .
```

That said, I agree with @eli-k's comment that clicking through the UI to generate syntax is a good way to ease into learning to write your own syntax.